# Add user-specified internal version to Solr core?

Tags: solr

I have a script that loads information about medications, like you would find in RxNorm, into a Solr core. There's a relatively constant schema for all of the documents. See below.

I would also like to add a document to the core with two properties:

1. the date on which the core was populated
2. the version of the software that did the population

Are there established ways to do that? I'm using R's `solrium` package.

Could this be considered a *bad idea*? Is there some way to lock the core so changes can't be made after the version document is added? I do have a customized `schema.xml`, but otherwise this is a pretty vanilla Solr setup.

---

#### Schema illustration

`select?q=medlabel%3Aacetaminophen`

gets

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"medlabel:acetaminophen"}},
  "response":{"numFound":4269,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/RXNORM/161",
        "medlabel":["acetaminophen"],
        "tokens":["acetaminophen"],
        "definedin":["http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/RXNORM/"],
        "employment":["IN"],
        "_version_":1674388636888465414},
      {
        "id":"http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_46195",
        "medlabel":["acetaminophen"],
        "tokens":["4-acetamidophenol",
          "acetaminophen",
          "apap",
          "panadol",
          "paracetamol",
          "tylenol"],
        "definedin":["http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/chebi.owl"],
        "employment":["active_ingredient"],
        "_version_":1674388639675580445},
      {
        "id":"http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/RXNORM/1006970",
        "medlabel":["acetaminophen / dimenhydrinate"],
        "tokens":["/",
          "acetaminophen",
          "dimenhydrinate"],
        "definedin":["http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/RXNORM/"],
        "employment":["MIN"],
        "_version_":1674388635062894610}
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a collection in read only mode after indexing your content into it [using `MODIFYCOLLECTION`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/collection-management.html#modifycollection). That will effectively give you a read-only collection which does not allow any updates.

My recommendation for your other case would be to have that field present on each document instead of as a separate document (which sure, that'd work as well). But if your number of documents is *very* large, add a separate document with the metadata you need.

However, you can *also* use `MODIFYCOLLECTION` for this to attach properties to the collection itself:

> The attributes that can be modified are:
>
> - other custom properties that use a property. prefix

So you can add `property.client_version` and `property.populated_datetime` properties to the collection itself, which would then be replicated properly across your cluster if needed. The collection also have a last index update time available, but this might be node specific (since the commits can happen in different timeframes on each node). It won't let you attach the client version anyhow.

Comment: Thanks. I'm **not** running in SolrCloud mode. Doesn't that mean that I won't be able to use the `MODIFYCOLLECTION` API call? Is there an easy way to switch to SolrCloud from the single core/compute node approach?

Comment: I like the versioning each document approach, too.

Comment: You can switch by starting your single node using `-c` - this will start Solr with its internal zookeeper node instead. There is a slight overhead (since you'll be running a zzokeeper node as well), but it's practically ignorable. You'll have to re-create your current core as a collection instead, and editing configuration (which have to go through Zookeeper) gets a few extra steps. If you're running in non-cloud mode, you can make the underlying file system read only after indexing, effectively making it impossible to commit any new information to the index.